# Mudar data attribute do HTML com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um input que gostaria de mudar o data-min e data-max com o valor trazido por AJAX ao mudar o valor do select category_id. O Ajax está trazendo o valor corretamente, mas não muda o valor do data-min e data-max.

HTML

```
<select id="category_id" class="form-control" name="category_id" required>
    <option value="">Selecione</option>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{$category->id}}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<input type="text" id="range_01" data-min="0" data-max="0">

$("#category_id").change(function() {
    var category = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'/customer/orders/lowerValueService/' + category,
        success:function(data){
            var value = data;
            console.log(value);
            $("#range_01").data("min", value);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("Erro");
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:'/customer/orders/highestValueService/' + category,
        success:function(data){
            var value = data;
            console.log(value);
            $("#range_01").data("max", value);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log("Erro");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Testa com `$("#range_01").attr("data-max", value);`, funciona?

Comment: Não funcionou..

Comment: Tinha feito algo errado, funcionou sim.

Comment: O `.data()` do jQuery funciona de maneira meio especial... onde precisas de usar esse `data-xxx` no código depois de lhe dares o valor do ajax?

Comment: Deu certo a maneira que passou. Pode colocar como resposta.

Comment: Sim, darei uma resposta, mas estou curioso de onde usas esse valor, pois pode ser que seja necessário usar noutros sítios, e gostava de explicar (para outros que leiam a resposta) o porquê do `.data` não funcionar.

Comment: Precisava que ao mudar o select ele mudasse o data-min e data-max para usar em outra função.

Comment: Ok, mostra essa outra função e a função que o select corre quando muda também.

Comment: É a função de um plugin. http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html